# MS SQL Hardware Configuration

Tags: raid, sql-server-2005, memory, configuration, database-mirroring

About to order a replacement mirrored database pair to drive our multi-user web applications and looking for some guidance on some aspects. I have read various feedback on other posts but finding it hard to put the feedback in context for our usage profile.

We are looking for the best bang for our (limited) buck.

Is the spec detailed below (planned) fit for purpose, and what aspects should we change if any - for example HDD types, memory levels, RAID configuration, processor?

Finally running mirroring in 2 directions simultaneously, are we correct to assume that we will get significantly better leverage on our hardware?

**Current System Config**

- Windows 2003 running SQL 2005 Standard 32 bit
- Multiple Databases - current sizes 23GB, 8GB, 7GB, 6GB, 5GB, 5GB, 2GB, and four sub 1GB
- Total Reads vs Total Writes gives a ratio of 2.5 to 1
- Mirroring running instance to instance (i.e idle hot swap) between 2 identical servers

  - 1xRAID 1 Array of 7.5K SATA running everything - no cache on RAID controller
  - 2GB Memory
  - Xeon Dual Core 1.8GHz

**Planned System Config**

- Windows 2008 R2 running SQL 2005 Standard 64 bit
- Split mirroring so that it is active in both directions at the same time - i.e. half of the databases will mirror in one way and the other half the other way to try to get better leverage on h/w
- 2 identical servers again:

  - Dell H700 RAID Controller with 1GB Cache
  - 1xRAID 1 Array of Near Line SAS 1TB for OS/Program Files/Transaction Logs
  - 1xRAID 1 Array of 600GB 15K SAS Drives for Databases
  - 8GB memory
  - Intel Quad Core 2.6GHz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you want to have Transactional Logs on a RAID 1 by themselves. User databases on a separate RAID depending on how many disks you can throw at it. RAID 10 for this would be one of the best options. Finally a RAID 1 for OS/Program Files etc... If you have the ability for more disks seperating TempDB onto its own array is also beneficial.

This article may help http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966534.aspx